# How to generate very sharp color scale for below zero and above zero?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm encountering a big problem when using the number `0 (zero)` as a factor for the colors to generate scales, the numbers close to `0 (zero)` end up becoming almost white, impossible to see a difference.

The idea is that above `0 (zero)` it starts green and gets even stronger and below `0 (zero)` starting with a red one and getting stronger.

I really need any number, even if it's `0.000001` already has a visible green and the `-0.000001` has a visible red.

Link to SpreadSheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uN5rDEeR10m3EFw29vM_nVXGMqhLcNilYrFOQfcC97s/edit?usp=sharing

*Note to help with image translation and visualization:*

```
Número = Number  
Nenhum = None  
Valor Máx. = Max Value
Valor Min. = Min Value
```

**Current Result / Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: Hi there @BrondbyIF! Could you please confirm all the conditional format rules? Please be aware that more than one colour scale could be used at the same time, meaning that you could have one green scale for positive values and one red scale for negative ones. If that doesn't help, please share a copy of your Sheet.

Comment: Hi mate @Jacques-GuzelHeron , The idea is that above zero it starts green and gets even stronger. So that later I create another one by putting it below zero starting with a red one and getting stronger. I even tried to use the red to green scale, but the values close to zero are very weak in color and I need to see the green or red sharper even at values close to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your new comments I understand that these are the requisites:

- The values above zero should be green (with increased intensity the further beyond zero).
- The values below zero should be red (with increased intensity the further beyond zero).
- Values near zero should be coloured (not almost white).

Given those requisites, I developed an Apps Script project that would be useful in your scenario. This is the full project:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu("Extra").addItem("Generate gradient", "parseData").addToUi();
}

function parseData() {
  var darkestGreen = "#009000";
  var lighestGreen = "#B8F4B8";
  var darkestRed = "#893F45";
  var lighestRed = "#FEBFC4";
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var biggestPositive = Math.max.apply(null, data);
  var biggestNegative = Math.min.apply(null, data);
  var greenPalette = colourPalette(darkestGreen, lighestGreen, biggestPositive);
  var redPalette = colourPalette(darkestRed, lighestRed, Math.abs(
    biggestNegative) + 1);
  var fullPalette = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] > 0) {
      var cellColour = [];

      cellColour[0] = greenPalette[data[i] - 1];
      fullPalette.push(cellColour);

    } else if (data[i] < 0) {
      var cellColour = [];

      cellColour[0] = redPalette[Math.abs(data[i]) - 1];
      fullPalette.push(cellColour);

    } else if (data[i] == 0) {
      var cellColour = [];

      cellColour[0] = null;
      fullPalette.push(cellColour);
    }
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(fullPalette);
}

function colourPalette(darkestColour, lightestColour, colourSteps) {
  var firstColour = hexToRGB(darkestColour);
  var lastColour = hexToRGB(lightestColour);
  var blending = 0.0;
  var gradientColours = [];

  for (i = 0; i < colourSteps; i++) {
    var colour = [];

    blending += (1.0 / colourSteps);
    colour[0] = firstColour[0] * blending + (1 - blending) * lastColour[0];
    colour[1] = firstColour[1] * blending + (1 - blending) * lastColour[1];
    colour[2] = firstColour[2] * blending + (1 - blending) * lastColour[2];
    gradientColours.push(rgbToHex(colour));
  }
  return gradientColours;
}

function hexToRGB(hex) {
  var colour = [];

  colour[0] = parseInt((removeNumeralSymbol(hex)).substring(0, 2), 16);
  colour[1] = parseInt((removeNumeralSymbol(hex)).substring(2, 4), 16);
  colour[2] = parseInt((removeNumeralSymbol(hex)).substring(4, 6), 16);

  return colour;
}

function removeNumeralSymbol(hex) {
  return (hex.charAt(0) == '#') ? hex.substring(1, 7) : hex
}

function rgbToHex(rgb) {
  return "#" + hex(rgb[0]) + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]);
}

function hex(c) {
  var pool = "0123456789abcdef";
  var integer = parseInt(c);

  if (integer == 0 || isNaN(c)) {
    return "00";
  }

  integer = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, integer), 255));

  return pool.charAt((integer - integer % 16) / 16) + pool.charAt(integer % 16);
}
```

First of all the script will use the [`Ui`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) class to show a customised menu called *Extra*. That menu calls the main function `parseData`, that reads the whole selection data with [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getvalues). That function holds the darkest/lightest green/red colours. I used some colours for my example, but I advise you to edit them as you wish. Based on those colours, the function `colourPalette` will use graphical [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) between the two colours (lightest and darkest). That interpolation will return an array with colours from darkest to lightest, with as many in-betweens as the maximum integer in the column. Please notice how the function uses many minimal functions to run repetitive tasks (converting from hexadecimal to RGB, formatting, etc…). When the palette is ready, the main function will create an array with all the used colours (meaning that it will skip unused colours, to give sharp contrast between big and small numbers). Finally, it will apply the palette using the [`setBackgrounds`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setbackgroundscolor) method. Here you can see some sample results:
[image: Example]

In that picture you can see one set of colours per column. Varying between random small and big numbers, numerical series and mixed small/big numbers. Please feel free to ask any doubt about this approach.

Comment: Hello friend, thank you very much for taking the time to answer me, but unfortunately none of the options solves my problem. I'll edit the question to make it clearer to understand, I'll put a better example of what I need, I apologize for not being able to think of a better way to explain it before.

Comment: Again I apologize for the first question that lacked details and now I updated it showing the expected result very clearly, demonstrating the real accuracy in the idea of colors that is my need, thank you very much in advance

Comment: I also share the access to the spreadsheet if you want to visually analyze and edit as you wish, my friend!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have just updated my answer based on the new example. Please give it a look and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi mate Jacques, unfortunately, the problem ends up persisting because the positive value ```1``` has the same color as negative value ```-1```, making the idea of different colors for positive and negative not materialize.

Comment: I understand that request. Unfortunately, the limitations of the conditionat format rules layering makes it difficult to create two scales at the same time (one green and one red). On the bright side, you could recreate your desired colour scale using an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) project, and I could help you with the scripting side. Would Apps Script be a valid solution in your scenario?

Comment: Absolutely, yes mate!  I have some projects that use App Script, but I never imagined that it also opened up the possibility of creating a color scale.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an Apps Script approach. Give it a look and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

A very small improvement to acques-Guzel Heron

I made it skip all non numeric values, beforehand it just errored out.

I added an option in the menu to use a custom range.

Thank you very much acques-Guzel Heron

```js
function onOpen() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    ui.createMenu('Extra')
  .addItem('Generate gradient', 'parseData')
  .addItem('Custom Range', 'customRange')
  .addToUi();
}

function parseData(customRange = null) {
    const darkestGreen = '#009000';
    const lighestGreen = '#B8F4B8';
    const darkestRed = '#893F45';
    const lighestRed = '#FEBFC4';
    let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if (customRange) {
    range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(customRange);
  }

    const data = range.getValues();
    const biggestPositive = Math.max.apply(null, data.filter(a => !isNaN([a])));
    const biggestNegative = Math.min.apply(null, data.filter(a => !isNaN([a])));
    const greenPalette = colorPalette(darkestGreen, lighestGreen, biggestPositive);
    const redPalette = colorPalette(darkestRed, lighestRed, Math.abs(biggestNegative) + 1);

    const fullPalette = [];
    for (const datum of data) {
        if (datum > 0) {
            fullPalette.push([greenPalette[datum - 1]]);
        } else if (datum < 0) {    
            fullPalette.push([redPalette[Math.abs(datum) - 1]]);
        } else if (datum == 0 || isNaN(datum)) {
            fullPalette.push(['#ffffff']);
        }
    }
    range.setBackgrounds(fullPalette);
}

function customRange() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    result = ui.prompt("Please enter a range");
    parseData(result.getResponseText());
}

function colorPalette(darkestColor, lightestColor, colorSteps) {
    const firstColor = hexToRGB(darkestColor);
    const lastColor = hexToRGB(lightestColor);
    let blending = 0;
    const gradientColors = [];

    for (i = 0; i < colorSteps; i++) {
        const color = [];

        blending += (1 / colorSteps);
        color[0] = firstColor[0] * blending + (1 - blending) * lastColor[0];
        color[1] = firstColor[1] * blending + (1 - blending) * lastColor[1];
        color[2] = firstColor[2] * blending + (1 - blending) * lastColor[2];
        gradientColors.push(rgbToHex(color));
    }

    return gradientColors;
}

function hexToRGB(hex) {
    const color = [];

    color[0] = Number.parseInt((removeNumeralSymbol(hex)).slice(0, 2), 16);
    color[1] = Number.parseInt((removeNumeralSymbol(hex)).slice(2, 4), 16);
    color[2] = Number.parseInt((removeNumeralSymbol(hex)).slice(4, 6), 16);

    return color;
}

function removeNumeralSymbol(hex) {
    return (hex.charAt(0) == '#') ? hex.slice(1, 7) : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(rgb) {
    return '#' + hex(rgb[0]) + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]);
}

function hex(c) {
    const pool = '0123456789abcdef';
    let integer = Number.parseInt(c, 10);

    if (integer === 0 || isNaN(c)) {
        return '00';
    }

    integer = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, integer), 255));

    return pool.charAt((integer - integer % 16) / 16) + pool.charAt(integer % 16);
}
```